# Swift / IOS - Auto resizing label with tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a table that displays a custom cell containing some user entered data. The length of this data varies and therefore I am implementing tableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension.

This works fine, but I want the label to have an inset of 10x10x10x10. When I override the drawTextInRect on the custom label the insets are drawn and that works OK.

The problem is that the auto resizing doesn't seem to take into account the new insets and therefore truncates the label text and I can't figure out how to get around this.

By doing  println() prior to drawing the rect and returning the cell I found that the cell is returned before the insets are drawn which would lead me to believe that I need to update the cell content somewhere to fix this?

**CustomNoteLabel**

```
class CustomNoteLabel: UILabel {
    override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) {

    var insets:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)

    println("Drawing insets")

    return super.drawTextInRect(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))

    }

}
```

**TableViewInit()**

```
    self.tableView = UITableView()
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height - 200)
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = true
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200.0
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
    self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "NoteTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
```

Thanks peoples!

Answer (score 0):

After playing around a bit more I set the label Auto-Shrink to minimum font scale 0.75 which has fixed the issue.